# I serialize this class using the Simple XML framework. I do not get the xml result I want

Tags: java, xml

Is it possible to have a normal-tag instead of self-closing tag?

xml class :

```
@Root(name = "testsimple")
public static class TestSimple{

    @Attribute(name = "id")
    private int clientId;

    @Attribute(name = "name")
    private String clientName;

    @Path("list")
    @ElementList(inline=true)
    private List<Feature> list;
} 

@Root(name = "ad")
public static class Feature{
    @Attribute(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Attribute(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

Expected result :

```
<testsimple id="id" name="name">
    <list>
        <feature id="id" name="name"></feature>
        <feature id="id2" name="name2"></feature>
    </list>
</testsimple>
```

actual result :

```
<testsimple id="id" name="name">
    <list>
        <feature id="id" name="name"/>
        <feature id="id2" name="name2"/>
    </list>
</testsimple>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: You should include the code that actually turns objects into XML. Like in: how are you configuring the tool/library? That part is missing.

Comment: Why is the difference between `<tag></tag>` and `<tag/>` important to you? They mean exactly the same thing, and any XML parser will handle them equally.

Comment: Thank you for answer.

The company that processes xml must define it as "<tag> </ tag>".

I am too absurd.